# How to pass full 'where' clause criteria to SSRS report?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, parameters, where-clause

I am working on a reporting web app, which shows reports depending on criteria specified.

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName WHERE ID > 100 AND PIN > 200
```

So, on the webapp, there would be a textbox, where user would enter `ID > 100 AND PIN > 200`.
Next time, the user would type `ID > 100 AND PIN > 200 OR CODE < 30`.
The user is free to type any criteria in the textbox.

How to apply this criteria in SSRS, on the report query?

Comment: Please note this is probably a TERRIBLE idea. You should at the very least - allow them to pick from the fields in a dropdown box and validate the values, then build the Where clause in code. As it stands this could cause major security and performance issues depending on the competency of the users. If they are writing pure SQL queries anyway why not just have them use management studio?

Comment: Thanks @Milney. I am aware of the security issues it can cause, but this screen would only be for the admins to configure the reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dynamic SQL

`DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(max)
SET @sql = 'SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM MyTable ' + CASE WHEN @Criteria <> ' ' THEN 'WHERE ' +  @Criteria ELSE ' ' END
EXEC(@sql)`

Comment: Thanks @niktrs. I had done +1 which negated the previous -1.

Comment: Thanks Nands. I ll agree with Milney that this is not a good idea from security perspective, so be cautious.

Comment: I would kindly request anyone disagrees with my solution to provide a comment or a better alternative. Thanks